# Servlet Filter vs. ServletRequestListener

Tags: java, listener, servlet-filters

I want to bind a JPA EntityManager to the current thread on each request (via ThreadLocal), what could be done via a ServletRequestListener or Filter. The listener looks cleaner and I don't need the additional possibilities of a filter in this case. But maybe the filter has an advantage I've missed.

Should I use a Servlet Filter or a ServletRequestListener to do that?

Comment: Are there thread guarantees made about the ServletRequestListener? You're sure it's invoked synchronously, on the same thread as the request handling?

Comment: The Servlet 3.0 spec says: "11.5 Listener Instances and Threading
[...] The container must maintain a reference to each listener instance until the last request is serviced for the Web application.
Attribute changes to ServletContext and HttpSession objects may ccur
concurrently. The container is not required to synchronize the resulting notifications to attribute listener classes. Listener classes that maintain state are responsible for the integrity of the data and should handle this case explicitly."
But that is not the answer to your question ... I *think* it would be in the same thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your purpose there's not much difference. But a listener is "cleaner" in the sense that someone reading your code will immediately know that the purpose of this code can't possibly be to intercept the request or alter it or do other things that a filter can do.

Spring, for example, uses a ServletRequestListener to allow Spring web-based apps that are not using Spring's own Web MVC framework to nonetheless get access to web-specific functionality such as session-scoped beans. See [this doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextListener.html).

Edit: just to be more clear, I mention Spring's RequestContextListener because it does *exactly* what you're talking about: create a ThreadLocal object to store data that can be accessed throughout the rest of the request lifecycle.

Comment: Can you pls clarify this for me? `ServletRequestListener` listens to `ServletRequestEvent` which is an event triggered for every incoming request. If I want to log the user-agent for every request to my web app, should I use this listener or a filter?

Comment: Either is probably ok.